# Makefile: eliminate element from a list

Tags: foreach, makefile, build, compilation, gnu-make

I have a variable list in my Makefile like that:

```
varglob := a1 a2 a3 a4 a5 a6
```

I want to create a new variable from varglob but eliminate some specific elements for example "a3".

I thought about foreach but my problem is that I don't know how I test with ifneq inside the foreach. So I tried to use shell like that:

```
varglobelim := $(foreach y, $(varglob), $(shell if [$(y) != "a3"]; then echo $y;fi))
```

But this solution doesn't success. I get an empty message.

Is there any other suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`filter-out` is your friend here:

```
varglob := a1 a2 a3 a4 a5 a6 b7 b8 b-whatever
has-no-ticket := a3 b%  # a3 and all the b's didn't pay the ride

varglobelim := $(filter-out $(has-no-ticket),$(varglob))
```